# Apply resource on a button

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-button

I'm new in LWUIT. I have created a theme for my MIDlet and applied it. The background of the `Form`, the `Label` and font change as defined in the theme but the `Buttons` on the `Form` do not change like I have defined them in my theme. What could be the problem? Here is a snippet of my code.

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Button;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;
import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;

public class mainMidlet extends MIDlet {

public void startApp() 
{

    Display.init(this);

    Resources r;
    try {
        r = Resources.open(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/TUNGtheme.res"));
        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("Theme 2"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //do something

    }

Form f = new Form("App using LWUIT!");
f.show();

Button tuskysButton = new Button("Tuskys");
f.addComponent(tuskysButton);

}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the UIID that you defined for the `Buttons` has the right name. I mean in the ResourceEditor you have to apply the style for elements called `Button`. If that is right, did you set selected and unselected style? If I can see a pair of screens from your Resource Editor, I could help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the Button is focused and you only defined the unselected style and not the selected/pressed styles.